# What makes Azure Key Vault is secure than Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

What makes Azure Key Vault is secure than Azure SQL DB? AZ SQL Provides transport security.

I am exploring Azure service to store and retrieve sensitive data. Azure Key Vault, marketing name tells me AKV is right choice.

All data currently resides in AZ SQL DB. AKV really brings one more additional AZ service headache to manage within the code.

Is Azure Key Vault is really secure when compared to AZ SQL DB?

Comment: If you don't use SQL authentication and only use AAD authentication then AKV is not required. What is your actual use case? KeyVault is just an annoying workaround for services that still don't support AAD authentication.

Comment: `KeyVault is just an annoying workaround for services that still don't support AAD authentication.` - With all due respect, Key Vault is much more than storing connection strings.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am using SQL authentication since my SF application have has not gotten to the point of using AAD.
What makes AKV as choice when using SQL authentication?

I have to store sensitive plain text. I have to choose between AKV or SQL Server. 
Even I feel it is annoying to inject another dependency in my application. I want to have practical real reason and proof to use AKV. Ideally I want to continue using AZ SQL DB.

Comment: @Datha it depends what you're trying to achieve. SQL supports data masking for sensitive data. key vault is more a place where you wanna store the sql username/password, encryption key etc.

Comment: well AKV works well with alternative Azure Services, such as DataFactory, you wouldn't want your secrets in a table in your db would you? another level of abstraction, whilst annoying can add additional security.

Comment: @GauravMantri if you are storing connection strings in KV, you are mixing configuration with secrets. It means if you need to check your configuration, you need privileged access to view secrets. This doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - my comment was based on your comment. (May be I misinterpreted it) but the inference I got from your comment was that one would use KV only for those services that still don't support AAD which doesn't sound right to me and hence my comment that KV is much more than storing those credentials.

Comment: You're correct it is much more than storing credentials. If every service supported MI authentication you could use it just for what it's really meant for - certificate management. I really don't think it's the right place to store non-sensitive items such as connection strings (without pwd's) even though most doco encourages it.

Comment: Case in point of incorrect overuse of keyvault https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68369932/setting-azure-keyvault-variable-in-devops-pipeline

Answer (score 7):

From a security perspective, you have fine granular control over who has which permissions to use your secrets. For example, you can give certain users "Set" permissions but only "Get" permissions for the application that uses the secret. Furthermore, in the Premium tier, Azure Key Vault can protect keys using a hardware security module (HSM) which can be a requirement in sensitive environments.

From a practical perspective, the most interesting aspect of Azure Key Vault for developers from my point of view is that it means that secrets no longer need to be stored in environment variables (or similar) during development but can be saved centrally in a Key Vault - and the code can be deployed to a cloud environment without modification.

An example: Imagine you work together with a coworker on a Python app that needs to authenticate with a third-party service that needs a password. You could store that password in Azure SQL, but to access Azure SQL, you again need credentials. How do you share these credentials with your coworker? Checking it into source control is not a good practice, you could share it over other channels and you both store it in a local environment variable but if this password changes or you onboard new people, the hassle starts again. By making use of Azure Key Vault, you could retrieve the password like this:

```py
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient("https://yourkeyvault.vault.azure.net/", credentials)
third_party_password = client.get_secret("third-party-password").value
```

`DefaultAzureCredential()` will automatically check several locations for credentials that can be used to get the secret from your Key Vault.

[image: https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/]

"Environment" means, if you have created an App registration and the following environment variables are set

```
AZURE_USERNAME
AZURE_PASSWORD
AZURE_TENANT_ID
```

`DefaultAzureCredential()` will use them to log in (of course in Key Vault the according access policies must be set so the user can read secrets).

If no environment variables are found, `DefaultAzureCredential()` checks in the next step if the app is running in an (Azure) environment where Managed Identity is available. In other words, if you use an [Azure App Service with Managed Identitiy turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet) and this managed identity has secret "Get" permissions on your Key Vault, `DefaultAzureCredential()` will use those permissions.

If you develop locally and you don't want to set environment variables, it's also possible to simply log into Azure with `az login` which will store an access token locally. `DefaultAzureCredential()` can use that token to log into Key Vault and retrieve the secret. In that case, neither the password nor the credentials to access Azure Key Vault have to be stored locally somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I reread your question and it sounds like you're asking whether to store secrets in the database or in key vault? You get a bunch of out-of-the-box features with KV that you don't get with a custom DB encryption and storage solution, at the very least it's cloud ready and supports many API's

I agree that it adds to solution complexity, but depending on what features you require, it's probably simpler and more secure than creating your own service in the database.