# Setting Azure KeyVault Variable in DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Hi I'm trying to create a file and upload it to a storage account within Azure. I can create the file and send it to the storage account if I hard code the values, such as storage account name, access key and container, however I'd like to save them in Azure Key Vault and reference them from there.

I have an ARM template running which I have my admin username and password in and it works perfectly using `"$(adminUser)"` and `"$(adminPass)"`

The code for the storage account is below:

```
$StorageAccountName = "$env:storageaccountname"
$StorageAccountKey = "$env:secretstoragekey"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$ContainerName = "$env:vhdcontainer"

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -file ./$Filename  -Container $ContainerName -Blob $Filename -Context $ctx -force
```

I have tried using `$(StorageAccountName)`, `$(secretstoragekey)` and `$(vhdContainer)` bu no joy. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong and point me in the right direction please.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by *KV*?

Comment: Edited question, sorry It should have said Key Vault, its Azure Key Vault which I have now added to the question. Thanks

Comment: If you use AAD authentication, you don't need a secret, and in my opinion you should not be storing config (storage account, container) in key vault because these are not secure secrets. Store them in DevOps variable groups instead.

Comment: But if you must... perhaps this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yeah, I think you're right about using Key Vault for variables which aren't secrets, we would like storage account name and SAS token in Key Vault, the link seems handy but doesn't show how to pass the variables from Key vault into an Azure DevOps pipeline using Powershell. It works with ARM templates, so bit confused

Comment: Sorry I did some deleting and editing.  I think this exact link shows how to grab a secret into a Powershell variable. But there are other ways https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell#retrieve-a-secret-from-key-vault

Comment: "we would like storage account name and SAS token in Key Vault" but these aren't secrets, these are environment specific configuration that actually belongs in DevOps variable groups.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid interesting, would the sas token be stored as a variable too but locked, we wouldn’t want that getting in the wrong hands.

Comment: My bad, yes the SAS token is a secret. But avoid it altogether by using AAD authentication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory This has it's own set of challenges but it takes a whole level of complexity out when you don't need a KV, and removes a security attack vector

Comment: If you need to stick with the SAS token it can be stored as a DevOps secret. However KeyVault secrets are probably a little easier to be "rotated"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks Nick, I’m unfortunately stuck with some storage accounts that I have to use, I’ll do some digging not sure if you can use both sas and AAD authentication as we already have some tools using sas tokens :(

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can use both SAS and AAD authentication simultaneously on the same storage account

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid excellent.. new challenge for tomorrow. Thanks for your help and if you mark that as an answer I’ll accept it

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I would need to go through and thoroughly provide working code before I would pose an answer and I don't have time right now. It would probably be helpful if you came back and reported your findings / progress for other people to observe

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yep, will do, thanks again